# Не обновлять страницу при прокрутке

Tags: javascript, jquery

На сайте есть scroll блок. При прокрутке (свайпом вниз), докручивая до определенного элемента идет динамическая подгрузка контента. Если крутить быстро, то можно этим жестом случаяно обновить страницу (например chrome). Как предотвратить эту ситуацию?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте CSS свойства

```
touch-action: none
```

```
overflow-y: hidden
```

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы сам блок прокручивался

Comment: А из-за свайпа винз, на мобильном устройстве может случайно обновиться страница

Comment: Можно скрин, пожалуйста?